# Laravel Eloquent multiple relations to same table

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I have the following table:

```
Table: rental_request
Columns:
id int(11) AI PK 
user_id int(11) 
address text 
number varchar(45) 
kvm varchar(45) 
rental varchar(45) 
zip varchar(45) 
city varchar(45) 
timestamp datetime 
created_at datetime 
updated_at datetime 
caseworker int(11)
```

Where `user_id` and `caseworker` points to my `users` table.

Now i am attempting to create this relationship in my `Laravel` application:

```
    class rental_request extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'rental_request';
    protected $fillable = ['user_id','address', 'number', 'kvm','rental','zip','city', 'caseworker'];

    public function user()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'user_id');
    }

    public function caseworker()
    {
        return $this->hasOne('App\User', 'user_id', 'caseworker');
    }
}
```

In my controller I collect the data from the table using:

```
rental_request::orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Now, this actually works but only for the `user` and not for the `caseworker`.

Which means I have a `user` object on my result but not a `caseworker` object.

Can anyone tell me what I've done wrong?

Comment: `hasOne` expects you to have like `caseworker_id` on `users` table.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can use with to get caseworker

```
rental_request::with(['caseworker','user'])->orderBy('id', 'desc')->get();
```

Comment: @Marc Rasmussen this couldn't possibly help you because this code just preloads relationships. Your `caseworker` relationship does not work because it was not defined correctly. You should use code from patricus' answer. Then both `$rentalRequest->caseworker` and `with('caseworker')` will work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Your caseworker relationship should also be defined as a `belongsTo` relationship. The `rental_request` model has the foreign key, so it belongs to the foreign model.

```
public function caseworker()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('App\User', 'caseworker');
}
```

Comment: i attempted this however no result

Comment: @MarcRasmussen Then I would guess that the `rental_request` record you attempted this on did not have an associated caseworker. This is how the relationship needs to be defined.